# Access violation when using python function in C++

Tags: python, c++

When I tried this code:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("print('hello')");
```

it works.

but when I tried this code:

```
PyObject* modStr = PyBytes_FromString((char*)"test");
PyObject* mod = PyImport_Import(modStr);
PyObject* pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(mod, (char*)"mul");
PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(2, 2.3,4.1);
PyObject* pVal = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,args);
double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(pVal);
```

it raises an access violation.

N.B.: my python file called: test.py and it contains a function called mul(a,b) that return just a*b.

How to solve the problem?
thanks

Comment: You need `PyObject* args = Py_BuildValue("(dd)", 2.3, 4.1);`.